# How to query users associated to a specific web application in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application that is hosted on Azure (web app) and it uses Azure Active Directory to manage users.

I just figured out how to query users using this query:

https://graph.windows.net/mytenantid/users?api-version=1.5

But it brings me all the users in the directory, not only the ones associated to my application.

What I need to do is to query the users only from that specific application, not all the users in the Directory. Is there a way of doint that?

Comment: One more thing I want to make clear: Usually, after enabling authentication with Azure AD, all users can login the WebApp, how you specify some apart users to the Web Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these users have have been assigned to your application (using the process documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal)) or have consented to it individually (as opposed to an admin consenting on behalf of the entire tenant) you can query for them by using the appRoleAssignedTo navigation property on the [ServicePrincipal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#serviceprincipal-entity) pertaining to your application.

That navigation property will get you a list of [AppRoleAssignments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approleassignment-entity), which represent all of the entities that have been assigned to this app.

The id of each of these entities (in your case, users, but these can also be Groups or other ServicePrincipals, which will be indicated in the princiaplType attribute) will be represented in the pricnipalId attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! It did the trick!
(Client had cancelled this request but changed their mind XD)

Answer (score 0):

So.. here is how I did it:

```
    var url = $"https://graph.windows.ne/{tenantId}/servicePrincipals/{objectID}/appRoleAssignedTo?api-version=1.5";
    var content = await ExecuteRequestAsync(url);
    var userPermissionsList = ConvertToEntityList<UserPermissionModel>(content);
```

ExecuteRequestAsync Method:

```
        public async Task<string> ExecuteRequestAsync(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);
                ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientID, secretKey);
                AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;

                authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resAzureGraphAPI, clientCred);
                var client = new HttpClient();

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
                request.Headers.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return content;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Then I serialized the content using the method below:

```
        private List<T> ConvertToEntityList<T>(string content)
        {
            List<T> entityList = new List<T>();

            // Create JavaScriptSerializer instance.
            JObject jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content) as JObject;
            var propperties = jsonObj.Properties().ToList();

            var entitiesTemp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(propperties[1].Value.ToString());// as JObject;
            entityList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(entitiesTemp.ToString());

            return entityList;
        }
```